# React Testing Library - How to see current state of the DOM when testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

I am learning React Testing Library (many years of TDD experience in other languages)

This documentation on the React Testing Library says that when `getByText` fails, it "however it prints the state of your DOM under test":

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/

[image]

However, this does not happen for me on the current RTL.

Instead, I get this:

```
  ● loads and displays greeting

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: the current weather is: overcast clouds. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <h1
      data-testid="currentWeatherOutput"
    />

      27 |   const currentWeatherOutput = screen.getByTestId('currentWeatherOutput')
      28 |
    > 29 |   getByText(currentWeatherOutput, "the current weather is: overcast clouds")
```

[image]

my package dependencies are

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "msw": "^0.38.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
```

I have two more questions:

1. Can I drop into a debugger directly inside my test code? https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/ mentions nothing about accessing a native JS debugger
2. Can I take a screenshot of the DOM (I guess no because this isn't actually headless?) and look at it?

Comment: From what I can tell. It does get logged: `<h1
      data-testid="currentWeatherOutput"
    />`. By Screenshot, do you mean literally print screen?. Or are you looking more for snapshots? Also would help us if you show your test case file.

Comment: uhh... yes but the DOM has more content than just the <h1> so I guess that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Need more info about code base. Are you using [react-testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro) for example? If not, why not? Or perhaps you're developing on react native and should [react-native testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-native-testing-library/intro). I can see you use `screen` from the base testing library functions but don't see how you're rending any components.

Answer (score 16):

> Can I take a screenshot of the DOM (I guess no because this isn't actually headless?) and look at it?

Yes. You absolutely can. Check out Jest Preview (https://github.com/nvh95/jest-preview)

[image: Jest Preview debug react testing library]

Jest Preview gives you the ability to "see" your app UI in a browser, instead of HTML in the terminal, just by 2 lines of code:

```js
import { debug } from 'jest-preview';

describe('App', () => {
  it('should work as expected', () => {
    render(<App />);
    debug();
  });
});
```

- Introduction: https://www.jest-preview.com/docs/getting-started/intro
- Installation guide: https://www.jest-preview.com/docs/getting-started/installation

Comment: Awesome library! Did you write that? 

Answer (score 3):

You can use screen.debug() to debug your document or elements
https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screendebug